Umbraco 13 Seamless SSO for Intranet
I'm building an intranet application on top of Umbraco 14 to allow for CMS functionality, and I'm looking to do some fairly basic stuff where I use the details of the person who's using the site for things like logging and personalisation, but I'm hitting a bit of a brick wall, and I'm hoping someone can help.
It's internal users, so the obvious means to authenticate would be Entra, which we use on other internal sites with no issues.  On Umbraco, it looks like authentication/authorization requires the use of the Members functionality, and to use Entra for that, I need to implement a login page and partial, with a button that triggers the Entra redirect flow.
With our other sites we simply redirect the user as soon as they hit the site, so the SSO is pretty seamless if they're already logged in, as they will be in pretty much all cases.
Is anyone aware of a way I can achieve this with Umbraco?  I don't need any member authorization restrictions for pages etc within Umbraco if that helps at all, and I'm fine with content editors still using username/password for CMS access, even if I end up applying authentication across the whole site and they're therefore already signed in as Entra users, so I'm fine with simply bypassing the members functionality as long as that won't kill Umbraco entirely.

While I was never able to sort out seamless SSO, I have now managed to at least implement the SSO and a persistent authentication cookie so that users are only prompted after a sensible period of time.  See link to separate question about the persistent authentication cookie.  Persistent Authentication Cookie for External Membership Provider Umbraco 13

Have you considered this approach to integrate Azure B2C with Umbraco users and members? Once the integration is complete, you can then check the logged-in user's claims to allow them access to protected Umbraco pages.
Following the Azure B2C setup on the Azure portal (Creating an Azure B2C tenant, registering the web application, configuring scopes, granting permissions, creating user flows and policies etc), you install the following packages to your Umbraco website, create new classes, similar to the ones that I created for my v13 website, to configure authentication for backoffice users and front-end members.
Microsoft.Identity.Web 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount

appsettings.json
      "AzureAdB2C": {
        "Instance": "https://projectnameb2c.b2clogin.com",
        "TenantId": "TenantId from Azure portal",
        "ClientId": "ClientId from Azure portal",
        "ClientSecret": "ClientSecret from Azure portal",
        "Domain": "projectnameb2c.onmicrosoft.com",
        "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/authentication/signout/",
        "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_SignUpandSignIn",
        "ReturnAfterLogout": "https://projectURL/", 
        "RedirectURI": "https://projectURL/", 
        "PostLogoutReturnUI": "https://projectnameb2c.b2clogin.com/projectnameb2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SignUpandSignIn/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri="
}

AzureB2CBackofficeExternalLoginProviderOptions
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Umbraco.Cms.Core;
using Umbraco.Cms.Web.BackOffice.Security;

namespace ProjectName.Web.UI.AzureB2C
{
    public class AzureB2CBackofficeExternalLoginProviderOptions : IConfigureNamedOptions<BackOfficeExternalLoginProviderOptions>
    {
        public const string SchemeName = "OpenIdConnect";
        public void Configure(string? name, BackOfficeExternalLoginProviderOptions options)
        {
            if (name != Constants.Security.BackOfficeExternalAuthenticationTypePrefix + SchemeName)
            {
                return;
            }

            Configure(options);
        }


        public void Configure(BackOfficeExternalLoginProviderOptions options)
        {
            //options.ButtonStyle = "btn-danger";
            options.Icon = "fa fa-cloud";
            options.AutoLinkOptions = new ExternalSignInAutoLinkOptions(



                // must be true for auto-linking to be enabled
                autoLinkExternalAccount: true,

                // Optionally specify default user group, else
                // assign in the OnAutoLinking callback
                // (default is editor)
                defaultUserGroups: new[] { Constants.Security.AdminGroupAlias },

                // Optionally specify the default culture to create
                // the user as. If null it will use the default
                // culture defined in the web.config, or it can
                // be dynamically assigned in the OnAutoLinking
                // callback.

                defaultCulture: null,
                // Optionally you can disable the ability to link/unlink
                // manually from within the back office. Set this to false
                // if you don't want the user to unlink from this external
                // provider.
                allowManualLinking: false
            )
            {
                // Optional callback
                OnAutoLinking = (autoLinkUser, loginInfo) =>
                {
                    //This has to be set! Or else when the user is created it will be marked as disabled!

                    autoLinkUser.IsApproved = true;



                    // You can customize the user before it's linked.
                    // i.e. Modify the user's groups based on the Claims returned
                    // in the externalLogin info
                },
                OnExternalLogin = (user, loginInfo) =>
                {
                    // You can customize the user before it's saved whenever they have
                    // logged in with the external provider.
                    // i.e. Sync the user's name based on the Claims returned
                    // in the externalLogin info

                    return true; //returns a boolean indicating if sign in should continue or not.
                }
            };

            // Optionally you can disable the ability for users
            // to login with a username/password. If this is set
            // to true, it will disable username/password login
            // even if there are other external login providers installed.
            options.DenyLocalLogin = false;

            // Optionally choose to automatically redirect to the
            // external login provider so the user doesn't have
            // to click the login button. This is
            options.AutoRedirectLoginToExternalProvider = false;

        }
    }
}

AzureB2CMembersExternalLoginProviderOptions
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Umbraco.Cms.Core;
using Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.Security;

namespace ProjectName.Web.UI.AzureB2C
{
    public class AzureB2CMembersExternalLoginProviderOptions : IConfigureNamedOptions<MemberExternalLoginProviderOptions>
    {
        public const string SchemeName = "OpenIdConnect";
        public void Configure(string? name, MemberExternalLoginProviderOptions options)
        {
            if (name != Constants.Security.MemberExternalAuthenticationTypePrefix + SchemeName)
            {
                return;
            }

            Configure(options);
        }

        //public void Configure(string? name, MemberExternalLoginProviderOptions options)
        //{
        //  throw new NotImplementedException();
        //}

        public void Configure(MemberExternalLoginProviderOptions options)
        {
            options.AutoLinkOptions = new MemberExternalSignInAutoLinkOptions(
                // Must be true for auto-linking to be enabled
                autoLinkExternalAccount: true,

                // Optionally specify the default culture to create
                // the user as. If null it will use the default
                // culture defined in the web.config, or it can
                // be dynamically assigned in the OnAutoLinking
                // callback.
                defaultCulture: null,

                // Optionally specify the default "IsApprove" status. Must be true for auto-linking.
                defaultIsApproved: true,

                // Optionally specify the member type alias. Default is "Member"
                defaultMemberTypeAlias: "Member"

            // Optionally specify the member groups names to add the auto-linking user to.
            //defaultMemberGroups: new List { "Group1" } --> Issue on github: https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/issues/12853
            )
            {
                // Optional callback
                OnAutoLinking = (autoLinkUser, loginInfo) =>
                {
                    // You can customize the user before it's linked.
                    // i.e. Modify the user's groups based on the Claims returned
                    // in the externalLogin info
                },
                OnExternalLogin = (user, loginInfo) =>
                {
                    // You can customize the user before it's saved whenever they have
                    // logged in with the external provider.
                    // i.e. Sync the user's name based on the Claims returned
                    // in the externalLogin info

                    return true; //returns a boolean indicating if sign in should continue or not.
                }
            };
        }

        
    }
}

MemberAuthenticationExtensions
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace ProjectName.Web.UI.AzureB2C
{
    public static class MemberAuthenticationExtensions
    {
        public static IUmbracoBuilder ConfigureAuthenticationMembers(this IUmbracoBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.ConfigureOptions<AzureB2CMembersExternalLoginProviderOptions>();



            builder.AddMemberExternalLogins(logins =>
            {
                //const string schema = MicrosoftAccountDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

                logins.AddMemberLogin(
                    membersAuthenticationBuilder =>
                    {
                        membersAuthenticationBuilder.AddOpenIdConnect(
                    membersAuthenticationBuilder.SchemeForMembers(AzureB2CMembersExternalLoginProviderOptions.SchemeName),
                    options =>
                    {
                        var config = builder.Config;

                        options.SaveTokens = true;
                        //Obtained from the AZURE AD B2C WEB APP
                        options.ClientId = config["AzureAdB2C:ClientId"];
                        //Obtained from the AZURE AD B2C WEB APP
                        options.ClientSecret = config["AzureAdB2C:ClientSecret"];
                        //Callbackpath - Important! The CallbackPath represents the URL to which the browser should be redirected to and the default value is /signin-oidc This should be unique!.
                        options.CallbackPath = "/umbraco-b2c-members-signin";
                        //Obtained from user flows in your Azure B2C tenant
                        options.MetadataAddress = config["AzureAdB2C:DiscoveryUrl"];
                
                        options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
                        {
                            ClaimsPrincipal? principal = context.Principal;
                            if (principal is null)
                            {
                                throw new InvalidOperationException("No claims found.. :(");
                                return;
                            }

                            var claims = principal.Claims.ToList();

                            Claim? email = claims.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Type == "emails");
                            if (email is not null)
                            {
                                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, email.Value));
                            }

                            Claim? name = claims.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Type == "name");
                            if (name is not null)
                            {
                                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, name.Value));
                            }

                            var authenticationType = principal.Identity?.AuthenticationType;
                            context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, authenticationType));
                        };
                    });
                    });
            });

            return builder;
        }
    }
}

BackofficeAuthenticationExtensions
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace ProjectName.Web.UI.AzureB2C
{
    public static class BackofficeAuthenticationExtensions
    {
        public static IUmbracoBuilder ConfigureAuthentication(this IUmbracoBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.ConfigureOptions<AzureB2CBackofficeExternalLoginProviderOptions>();

            builder.AddBackOfficeExternalLogins(logins =>
            {
                //const string schema = MicrosoftAccountDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

                logins.AddBackOfficeLogin(
                    backOfficeAuthenticationBuilder =>
                    {
                        backOfficeAuthenticationBuilder.AddOpenIdConnect(
                    backOfficeAuthenticationBuilder.SchemeForBackOffice(AzureB2CBackofficeExternalLoginProviderOptions.SchemeName),
                    options =>
                    {
                        var config = builder.Config;

                        //options.ResponseMode = "query";
                        options.ResponseType = "id_token token";

                        options.Scope.Add("https://projectnameb2c.onmicrosoft.com/api/demo.read");
                        options.Scope.Add("https://projectnameb2c.onmicrosoft.com/api/demo.write");
                        options.Scope.Add("email");
                        options.Scope.Add("openid");
                        options.Scope.Add("offline_access");

                        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;

                        //Obtained from the AZURE AD B2C WEB APP
                        options.ClientId = config["AzureAdB2C:ClientId"];
                        //Obtained from the AZURE AD B2C WEB APP
                        options.ClientSecret = config["AzureAdB2C:ClientSecret"];
                        //Callbackpath - Important! The CallbackPath represents the URL to which the browser should be redirected to and the default value is /signin-oidc.
                        options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
                        //Obtained from user flows in your Azure B2C tenant
                        options.MetadataAddress = config["AzureAdB2C:DiscoveryUrl"];
                        options.TokenValidationParameters.SaveSigninToken = true;
                        options.SaveTokens = true;
                        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                        // It's important to have the correct claims set up in Azure.
                        // Once you are authenticated to Azure AD B2C, it validates the request. If the token is validated it triggers this event.
                        // The token coming back from Azure AD B2C, contains several properties and one of the properties is the claims, containing information about the email address and name, and these are used by Umbraco to create and link the user.

                        options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
                        {
                            ClaimsPrincipal? principal = context.Principal;
                            if (principal is null)
                            {
                                throw new InvalidOperationException("No claims found.. :(");
                                return;
                            }

                            var claims = principal.Claims.ToList();

                            Claim? email = claims.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Type == "emails");
                            if (email is not null)
                            {
                                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, email.Value));
                            }

                            Claim? name = claims.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Type == "name");
                            if (name is not null)
                            {
                                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, name.Value));
                            }

                            var authenticationType = principal.Identity?.AuthenticationType;
                            context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, authenticationType));
                        };
                    });
                    });
            });

            return builder;

        }
    }
}

Program.cs
using ProjectName.Web.Services.Implementations;
using ProjectName.Web.Services.Interfaces;
using ProjectName.Web.Extensions;
//using ProjectName.Web.UI.AzureB2C.OpenIdConnect;
using ProjectName.Web.UI.Startup;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Umbraco.Cms.Core.Services;
using ProjectName.Web.UI.AzureB2C;

WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var env = builder.Environment;
var config = builder.Configuration;

// Register application services
builder.RegisterApplicationServices(env, config);

//builder.Services.AddDynamics365Service(config);

builder.CreateUmbracoBuilder()
    .AddBackOffice()
    .AddWebsite()
    .AddDeliveryApi()
    .AddComposers()
    .ConfigureAuthentication()
    .ConfigureAuthenticationMembers()
    //.AddOpenIdConnectAuthentication()
    .Build();

builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(config, "AzureAdB2C");

builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
});

WebApplication app = builder.Build();

// Starting from Umbraco v12, Startup.cs doesn't exist any longer.
// This is because Umbraco has introduced Microsoft's Minimal Hosting Model which simplifies the initiation of Umbraco applications.
// Going forward, we shouldn't have Startup.css in our future Umbraco projects.
// New Umbraco v13 Helper: Ensure that Umbraco dependencies are loaded correctly.
// Following Umbraco upgrades to v13, if the following line is missing, add it.
await app.BootUmbracoAsync();

// Configure middleware
app.ConfigureMiddleware(env, config);

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseUmbraco()
    .WithMiddleware(u =>
    {
        u.UseBackOffice();
        u.UseWebsite();
    })
    .WithEndpoints(u =>
    {
        u.UseInstallerEndpoints();
        u.UseBackOfficeEndpoints();
        u.UseWebsiteEndpoints();
    });

await app.RunAsync();


I have specifically mentioned that I have tried this method (albeit without B2C), and that this is a site for internal users, so B2C would not be appropriate, but yes, I have considered this, and it requires the use of an interactive login button which is precisely what I'm looking to avoid.
